# Conditional classes on single instances of component within a loop

Tags: reactjs

I have a loop of components that make a grid and I want some instances to have a background color change triggered by adding a class.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455732/react-how-change-state-of-single-component-when-there-are-multiple-instance-of) question gave me ideas but I've yet to get them to work.

I have this basic markup in it.

```
   <div className={`box ${(this.state.backgroundColor ? 'backgroundColor' : null)}`} key={i}>
  </div>
```

And I have an array of the indexes representing the component instances that I want the color changed on

```
let indexes = [101, 178, 232, 545]
```

Currently I am doing it with plain JS, via `document.querySelector('.box:nth-of-type(101')`, but as this method bypasses React I want to change it.

Based on the other question I tried making an array of all the components and setting that to state, then looping through and using the indexes. I don't know how to "access" the component like this and get `$$typeof: Symbol(react.element) etc`

```
   let compArr = []
    this.arr.map((i) => {
        compArr.push(
            <div className={`box ${(this.state.backgroundColor ? 'backgroundColor' : null)}`} key={i}>
            </div>
        )
    })
    this.setState({
        compArr: compArr
    })
```

Then later loop over indexes:

```
indexes.map(index => {
    this.state.compArr[index] ===> ??stuck here??
})
```

Expected Output: So on an array of three instances, say I want the second one only to have the class of `backgroundColor`:

```
<div className='box' </div>
<div className='box backgroundColor'</div>
<div className='box'</div>
```

Only in my case, I want the instances to correlate with the `indexes` array

How can I set the conditional class to `true` in those instances I have in the array? Say I have like 500+ instances total.

Comment: Can you share more details about your expected output?

Comment: what's indexes? why not just loop through compArr ?

Comment: @Justcode Updated with expected output. Is that helpful at all?

Comment: @MoteZart I think you shouldn't be using array in this case, you should use a key value pair, where keys could be your indexes based on which you want to change the color and `<div className={`box ${(this.state.backgroundColor ? 'backgroundColor' : null)}`} key={i}>
            </div>` could be the value

Comment: @Afaq the instance have refs that could be useful in a loop, but then I'm still going something like `this.ref.current.style.backgroundColor = 'green'` Which is almost the same as what I have now.

Comment: @Afaq Can U give that in an answer, or at least a bigger example? I've done something like that in Vue before, using objects in the classes, but not sure if it's what U mean.

Comment: can you using Object Instead of Array ? `let compArr = {}`

Comment: @yasin Sure can. How can I cycle that through to get those `indexes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this is proably what you're looking for...

```js
let indexes = [101, 178, 232, 545]

let compArr = this.arr.map((obj, i) => {
    return (
        <div 
          className={`box${( indexes.includes(i) ? " backgroundColor" : "")}`} 
          key={i}
        >
        </div>
    );
})
this.setState({
    compArr: compArr
})
```

If your goal is **only** to return the given div with the className `backgroundColor` for every element in `this.arr` with its index included in the `indexes` array then...

1. You only need to iterate over the array once and can perform all the necessary logic you're currently doing performing in two.
2. You don't need to use `Array.push()` to an outside collector when using any of the pure functions like `map() or reduce()` because they return a new version of whatever array is iterated over.
3. If for whatever reason you want a distinct array of `<div>`s with an index in `indexes` then you should use reduce...

```js
let compArr = this.arr.reduce((acc, obj, i) => {
    if (!indexes.includes(i)) return acc;
    return [ 
       ...acc,
       <div className="box backgroundColor" key={i}></div>
    )]
},[])
```

Comment: Part one of the answer is _exactly_ what I asked for here. I just wish I knew why it was not working. +1 for seeing what I was asking for.

Comment: Ah, yes you're right. I just updated example 1, which should have returned an empty string in the null case.

Comment: Ok shoot, thats not how it should function. Give me one second, I've been doing this in my head, but let me debug it real quick...

Comment: I'm getting something that will return true to the instances. Great! Using indexes.includes(i) ? 'backgroundColor' : '' as U provided I can confirm that true is being returned for the numbers that match .includes. The element has a class of blank string though (or null if I use that) , and for some reason `backgroundColor is not being added. It might be a timing issue but I check for existence before it even gets here so not sure how it could be possible. Arg

Comment: Actually, I take that back the solution I provided should work, but just made another edit to remove that empty space when backgroundColor isn't included. See this working example... https://codesandbox.io/s/4w52x126n9

Comment: If you'd like me to troubleshoot the issue you're seeing then you'll have to provide a working example or the code from the file you're working on. The Gist you provide is empty. To provide me access to that Gist you'll have to give me link from the 'Embed/Share/Clone' drop-down at the top of the page.

Comment: The gist is prob not going to help, but here it is  https://gist.github.com/chrisdel101/07731f53ece364a7e3825588c9f5e900  It's a typical example. I'll work on a replication. I think the prob is the array of boxes is 40000 long so this might be causing the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187144/discussion-between-mote-zart-and-cantuket).