# Why does ternary in conditional class logic not provide the correct value?

Tags: reactjs

I have a conditional class that should return the class name when true but it does not, even when true is returned. (I believe) This is due to the giant array of 40000 units I'm using to render a graph.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drumgod/L7safqjz/165/)

In the fiddle I want the class to be added to boxes 100, 101, and 102 on click. This should change the color.

This approach is a follow-up to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54301309/conditional-classes-on-single-instances-of-component-within-a-loop/54301579#54301579) that works in theory,  but is not working in practice due to size of the array. I know this is absurd to have an array this large rendering a grid like this, but I'm invested and want to fix this. (But I'm open to other suggestions)

I want the below to add the class to some of the instances of the graph of 40000. When `i` matches and array of the boxes that should change color.

`i` is looping through `1...40000` while rendering a graph.

`let indexes = [100,101,102]`

`<div className={'box ${indexes.includes(i) ? 'background-color' : 'null'}'}>`

`typeof(indexes.includes(i))` will be a Boolean.

I can see that true is returned and yet the class does not get added. However, if I try with a smaller array it works, so it seems it is a timing issue. `setTimeout` does not work here and causes the re-render to fail entirely.

The expected output should be, on `document.querySelector('.box-container:nth-of-type(100')`, 101, 102:

`<div className='box background-color'></div>`

But it is:

`<div className='box null'></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is working example with some additional 'best practices' and corrections that will make you code more performant and readable...

https://jsfiddle.net/cantuket3/3cs7abyg/9/

(Oops, I provided a link to you example by accident initially. This one works)

(Also, I removed the inline snippets that were here a minute ago. The formatting that editor produced was completely illegible. Refer to jsFiddle above.)

1. You should move as much logic out of the render function as possible because every time React detects changes to state (which modify the UI) it will run the render function again. Also, makes your code more modular and readable...

```js
render(){
    return(
   this.props.toRender.map(num => {
       return  <React.Fragment key={Math.random()}>
       
              {this.renderBoxes(num)}
            </React.Fragment>
        
        })    
        )
 }
```

TO

```js
render(){
    if (this.props.toRender && this.props.toRender.length) {
     return(
          <React.Fragment>
              {this.renderBoxes()}
          </React.Fragment>
      )       
     } else {
      return (
        <div>
          No Boxes yet!
        </div>
   )
  }
}
```

2. This is unnecessary if you are defining this array imperativel. Just drop in the elements directly...

```js
    arr.push(100)
    arr.push(101)
    arr.push(102)
    this.setState({
       classesToAdd: arr
    })
```

TO

```js
this.setState({
    classesToAdd: [10,11,12]
})
```

3. React only needs a 'key' when there a series of sibling elements, so it can optimize change detection.

`<button key={Math.random()} onClick={this.updateState.bind(this)}>Add Classes</button>`

TO

`<button onClick={this.clickToAdd.bind(this)}>Add Class</button>`

Comment: I can't get the above render method to work as it, but I get the idea. I don't see exactly how U got the example to work but this should help me solve the problem.

Comment: There are more modifications than just the render method and the stuff listed... there was quite a bit to clean up. You should probably get the code I provided running, take a look through yours line by line and then let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: How does this work in the parent in the example? `render(){
    return(
   this.props.toRender.map(num => {
       return  <React.Fragment key={Math.random()}>
              {this.renderBoxes(num)}
            </React.Fragment>
        
        })    
        )
 }` Where do U pass the props in?

Comment: I rewrote the `renderBoxes()` function almost entirely because you were using it incorrectly. The `map()` over the array now happens entirely in  `renderBoxes()`, which builds the JSX elements. The `render()` function then does just that... render them.

Comment: As I mentioned in the Solution, its better to move as much logic out of `render()` as possible

Comment: Okay. I just don't see where U are even rendering `Box` and the `renderBoxes` is a function on the child. I didn't know U could call child functions on the parent. So there some basics I guess I might be missing. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Well there are 2 components in this file `Box` and `Grid` and  `Grid` renders `Box`. You should actually be pulling `Box` out into a separate file and `import` it into the file where you defined you `Grid` component to make your code more organized.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187200/discussion-between-mote-zart-and-cantuket).